# Allocating memory to char* C language

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

Is it the correct way of allocating memory to a char*.

```
char* sides ="5";

char* tempSides;

tempSides = (char*)malloc(strlen(inSides) * sizeof(char));
```

Comment: @brickner what about this in strlen, 

strlen(inSides) + 1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Almost. Strings are NUL terminated, so you probably want to allocate an extra byte to store the NUL byte. That is, even though `sides` is 1 character long, it really is 2 bytes: {`5`,`'\0'`}.

So it would be:

```
tempSides = (char *)malloc((strlen(sides)+1)*sizeof(char));
```

and if you wanna copy it in:

```
strcpy(tempSides, sides);
```

Comment: You mean '\0' when you say NULL.  '\0' is nul, not NULL.

Comment: Note that multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is unneccesary; `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1.

Comment: @caf: True, but omitting it makes it harder to adapt code to wchar_t or TCHAR when necessary - if there're no multiplications there's a risk of forgetting to use one.

Comment: Don't forget to check for NULL before the `strcpy`

Comment: @sharptooth: Multiplying by `sizeof *tempSides` would be best if you're concerned about switching to `wchar_t` later.

Comment: @George Phillips: Strictly speaking, you mean 'null character'. `nul` is the ASCII moniker for the null character; the term 'nul' does not appear anywhere in the C standard.

Comment: @R Samuel Klatchko: how do you propose doing such a check, and what would the possible consequences be? If there's no `\0` after the input, both `strlen()` and `strcpy` would fail in the same way as your proposed check.

Comment: @MSalters: he meant checking the `malloc` return value.

Comment: I'd use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`.  In this case we know that the buffer is big enough, so `strcpy` is OK.  However, I prefer to avoid `strcpy` in ALL cases.  The overhead is so tiny you are unlikely to see a real difference in performance.

Answer (score 10):

Note that:

1. Strings are zero-terminated (\0), and strlen() doesn't count it;
2. By definition, sizeof(char) is 1 (byte), so it's not required;
3. If you use a C (not C++) compiler, there's no need to cast it to `char *`;

So that would be:

```
char *tempSides = malloc(strlen(inSides) + 1);
```

Still, if you want to *duplicate* the contents of `inSides`, you can use `strdup`, e.g.:

```
char *tempSides = strdup(inSides);
if (tempSides != NULL) {
    // do whatever you want...
    free(tempSides);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out, you missed allocating space for the terminating NUL chararacter.  But I also wanted to point out a couple of other things that can make your code more concise.

By definition, `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so you can shorten your allocation line to:

```
tempSides = (char*)malloc(strlen(inSides) + 1);
```

Another thing is that this looks like you are doing to duplicate the string.  There is a built in function that does that for you:

```
tempSides = strdup(inSides);
```

This handles getting the length, allocating the correct number of bytes and copying the data.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with that. tempSides will point to an uninitialized block of memory of size 1.  If you intend to copy the sides string into tempSides, then you will need to allocate a size one byte longer, in order to hold the zero terminator for the string.  The value returned by strlen() does not include the zero terminator at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. As others have already noted, you need to allocate space for the NUL terminator.

In addition, you generally should *not* cast the return from `malloc`. It can cover up a bug where you've forgotten to `#include` the correct header. Multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is also pointless, since the standards (both C and C++) define `sizeof(char)` to always be 1.

Finally, every call to `malloc` should include a test of the result. I'd wrap the whole thing up into a function:

```
char *dupe_string(char const *string) { 
    char *temp;
    if (NULL!=(temp=malloc(strlen(string)+1)))
        strcpy(temp, string);
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the element count by `sizeof(char)` is a matter of personal preference, since `sizeof(char)` is always 1. However, if you do this for consistency, better use the recipient pointer type to determine the element size, instead of specifying type explicitly. And don't cast the result of `malloc`

```
tempSides = malloc(strlen(inSides) * sizeof *tempSides);
```

Of course, when working with zero-terminated strings you have to remember to allocate extra space for the terminating zero character. There's no way to say whether it is your intent to make `tempSides` a zero-terminated string in this case, so I can't say whether you need it.

Comment: No way? He better should use zero-terminated strings when calling `strlen`... If he uses his own strlen, then I really don't want to be the maintenance programmer after him. ;)

Comment: @Secure: That only means that `inSides` is zero-terminated. There's no indication in the code that `tempSides` should be zero-terminated as well.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of allocation dynamic memory to `tempSides` is as shown below:

```
char* sides ="5";
char* tempSides;
tempSides = (char*)malloc((strlen(sides) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

`char*` stores a string data, similar to `char[]`. Strings are `null (\0)` terminated. So extra one byte should be allocated for `null` character storage.

Dynamically allocated memory block must be freed using `free()` after it's use is over. If not freed, memory leak would happen.

```
free(tempSides);
```

One the memory is freed, `NULL` must be assigned to prevent it from being a dangling pointer.

```
tempSides = NULL;
```