# Segmentation fault on char

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault when I run prog.c. I have found that it is something with my *char. Here's the code.

prog.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "worker.h"
#include "manager.h"
#include "employee.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int i;
  Worker boss = (Worker) new_Manager("Carl Cracker", 80000, 1987, 12, 15);
  return 0;       
}
```

worker.h

```
#ifndef _WORKER_H_
#define _WORKER_H_

 #define WORKER   char *name;   \
          double salary;    \
          long hireDay; \
          void (*raiseSalary)(Worker this, double byPercent);   

typedef struct Worker_struct* Worker;
struct Worker_struct {
   WORKER;
} Worker_struct;

void raiseSalary(Worker this, double byPercent);

#endif
```

worker.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "worker.h"

void raiseSalary(Worker this, double byPercent) {
  Worker worker = (Worker) this; 
  printf("worker_c: raising salary\n");
  double raise = worker->salary * byPercent / 100;
  worker->salary = worker->salary + raise;
}
```

manager.h

```
#ifndef _MANAGER_H_
#define _MANAGER_H_

#include "worker.h"


typedef struct Manager_struct* Manager;
struct Manager_struct {
  WORKER;
  double bonus;
void (*setBonus)(Worker this, double b);
} Manager_struct;

Manager new_Manager(char *name, double salary, int year, int month, int day);
#endif
```

manager.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "manager.h"

static void setBonus(Worker this, double b) {
  Manager manager = (Manager) this; 
  manager->bonus = b;
}

Manager new_Manager (char *name, double salary, int year, int month, int day) {
  Manager manager;
  strcpy (manager->name, name);//----i think my problem is here----
 manager->salary = salary;
 manager->bonus = 0;    
 manager->setBonus = setBonus;
 manager->raiseSalary = raiseSalary;

return manager;
}
```

I think that my problem is in the manager.c at strcpy. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `char *name` in the `WORKER` macro, but memory hasn't been allocated to it.

Please, please don't define variables in macros like this; there's absolutely no benefit, and it complicates the code unnecessarily.  Just define them directly in the `Worker_struct`.

Comment: I moved everything out of WORKER and into Worker_struct and Manager_struct, but I am getting the same Segmentation fault

Comment: @user821863 also you have not allocated memory for `manager`  in `newManager`

Comment: You've `typedef`ed `Manager` (why?) to be a pointer to a structure.  As @keety notes, you need to allocate memory for _every_ pointer, including that one.

Comment: I see what you mean, I have tried but still with no success. 
Manager new_Manager (char *name, double salary, int year, int month, int day) {
Manager manager;
manager = (Manager) malloc(sizeof(Manager_struct));
malloc (strlen (name + 1));
strcpy (manager->name, name);

Comment: @user821863 did you mean `malloc(strlen (name) + 1);` note the parenthesis also not a good practice to  typecast the return value of malloc just `include<stdlib.h>` lookup SO for why.

Comment: It does work. I allocated it wrong. this helped [stackoverflow allocating memory...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971709/allocating-memory-to-char-c-language)